# Проверить, подходит ли строка под условие и вырезать из неё два символа

Tags: javascript

Есть строка, которую я получаю обратившись к `document.location.pathname` - **/airlines/su/**.

Что мне нужно сделать с этой строкой? Изначально, нужно проверить, содержит ли строка что-то ещё кроме `/airlines/`. Сделать я это хотел при помощи регулярного выражения, которое проверяет, подходит ли строка под `/airlines/NN/`, но не знаю, как это сделать. Есть вариант взять длину строки `/airlines/` и сравнить её с тем, что в `document.location.path`, но срабатывать это будет при том условии, если написать в адресную строку что угодно. Поэтому этот вариант не подходит. Но помимо того, что мне нужно проверить эту строку, мне нужно ещё вырезать два символа : `/airlines/`**NN**`/`. Ну и напоследок, нужно проверить, являются ли эти два символа **NN** буквенно-числовыми и содержать они должны строго два символа. Варианты, которые подходят: s7, su, ps, a1. Есть ли какой-то элегантный способ сделать это в пару строк? А то моё описание выглядит уж слишком громоздким.

Comment: и что вам помешало написать это регулярное выражение? `^\/airlines\/([a-z\d]{2})\/$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var strings = [
  '/airlines/su/',
  '/airlines/s1/',
  '/airlines/22/',
  '/airlines/sup/',
  '/airlines/s/'
];

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  var match = strings[i].match(/\/airlines\/([a-z0-9]{2})\//i);
  if (match)
    console.log('Str: ' + strings[i] + ', code: ' + match[1]);
  else
    console.log('Str: ' + strings[i] + ', code: Not found');
};
```

Comment: что-то мне кажется, что `22`исключить надо

Comment: @teran автор скажет - исключим. Сейчас у него `два символа NN буквенно-числовыми и содержать они должны строго два символа.`

Comment: @teran нет, с `22` всё нормально, такое значение тоже может быть.

Comment: Спасибо за решение!

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Если мой ответ помог Вам, отметьте его как правильный